# How to update Apache 2.4.7 to Apache 2.4.11

Tags: updates, apache2

I am new to Ubuntu. Currently, my server (DigitalOcean) is using Ubuntu 14.04.1LTS with Apache 2.4.7.

How do I update Apache to the latest version?

I tried `apt-get` to update the system but the Apache version is still same:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

I want to update Apache 2.4.7 to 2.4.11
http://httpd.apache.org/security/vulnerabilities_24.html

Comment: Don't look at the upstream version numbers, read the [changelogs](http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/a/apache2/apache2_2.4.7-1ubuntu4.1/changelog) instead. The fixes in 2.4.10 have been backported to Ubuntu's 2.4.7, so I'd guess the fixes in 2.4.11 will be backported soon too.

Comment: Dear muru, that mean when i use sudo apt-get update will update the 2.4.10 backported to apache2.4.7 right?

Comment: If your apache version is `2.4.7-1ubuntu4.1` (check with `apt-cache policy apache2`), then yes, you have the backported fixes.

Comment: Thank You muru , Yes is the latest version. may i ask a last question Currently I using the http://sitecheck.sucuri.net/ to scan my web-sites the scanner is telling me Outdated Web Server Apache Found (Vulnerabilities on Apache 2.4.7) should i just ignored this?

Comment: If that site relies on version numbers instead of actually testing the vulnerability, yes. But I don't know how they test it, so I have no recommendations.

Answer (score 2):

Apache 2.4.11 has yet to be released as a full package, as of today it's still in the development tree. That means you should check out and compile the source by yourself. As  a trade-off solution you could step up a few versions and get as much updated an Apache2 package as the Debian Apache2 team have released by adding these PPAs to your list of repositories:

https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/apache2

https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php5

(the second link goes for php 5.5 support)

You may follow these web page's instructions or go the easiest way by issuing these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/apache2
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5
```

If add-apt-repository is not available in your VPS, install it.

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
```

Or, on older Ubuntu versions:

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
```